# Java - why will this only let me add to an arraylist when it is passed from main?

Tags: java, arraylist

This line, **result.add(temp.get(temp.size() - 3));** shows an error when the ArrayList is local to the threeConsecutiveInt method; note I've made sure only that is showing error, and it's not syntax, or failure to define. Temp would too if I moved it back. I can add to the list

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO code application logic here
            ArrayList<Integer> colInts = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
            //ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
            colInts.add(54);
            colInts.add(4);
            colInts.add(544);
            colInts.add(1237);
            colInts.add(98757);
            colInts.add(874);
            colInts.add(54987);
            colInts.add(874);
            colInts.add(154987);
            System.out.println(colInts);
            //System.out.println(threeConsecutiveInt(colInts, temp, result));
            System.out.println(threeConsecutiveInt(colInts, temp));
        }

        public static ArrayList<Integer> threeConsecutiveInt(ArrayList ints, ArrayList temp) { // , ArrayList result
            ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

            int start = 0;
            int count = ints.size() - 1;
            int size = count;
            for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
                temp.add(ints.get(i));
            }
            Collections.sort(temp);
            result.clear();
            result.add(temp.get(temp.size() - 3));
            //result.add(temp.get(temp.size() - 2));
            //result.add(temp.get(temp.size() - 1));
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                ints.remove(ints.size() - 1);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: How great would it be if you posted the error? (Post the error.)

Comment: I'm guessing you want to include the types on your generics in `threeConsecutiveInt`. Right now you could pass in any `ArrayList`, not just an `ArrayList` of `Integers`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post the actual error message, I'm only guessing here, but I'm pretty sure that the problem is that your formal method parameters are raw generic types. Since `result` is an `ArrayList<Integer>` You need the formal arguments to also be specifically `ArrayList<Integer>` for the call to `result.add()` to work. Change your function declaration from this:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> threeConsecutiveInt(
    ArrayList ints,
    ArrayList temp)
{
```

to this:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> threeConsecutiveInt(
    ArrayList<Integer> ints,
    ArrayList<Integer> temp)
{
```

Answer (score 0):

the temp parameter of threeConsecutiveInt is declared as a ArrayList (without type specification) so its get() method returns type Object but result only accepts Integer instance.

Change the method declaration to:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> threeConsecutiveInt(ArrayList<Integer> ints, ArrayList<Integer> temp) { // , ArrayList result
        ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
```